# php:SOAP failed to load external entity

Tags: php, web-services, soap, sap

This is my code (trying to consume SAP webservice)

```
$options = array( 
            'exceptions'=>true, 
            'trace'=>1,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            "login" => $this->ws_username,
            "pass" => $this->ws_password
          );

$this->client = new SoapClient($uri,$options);
print_r($this->soap_result);
```

this is the result (**the address is not real but in the same structure**)

```
Array
(
    [message] =System error
    [soap_exception] =SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://subdomain.sap.domain.com:50000/dir/wsdl?p=sa/Fca45c5131bb33eb0a4v5f1977ca80b92&WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://subdomain.sap.domain.com:50000/dir/wsdl?p=sa/Fca45c5131bb33eb0a4v5f1977ca80b92&WSDL"

)
```

Any thoughts about what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "password" instead of "pass"